# Pygame + Cron Trigger function

Tags: python, pygame

I've been making a game by using pygame for some time.
I've already made player stats like Hungry, Thirst etc.
I'd like to make this parameters to decrease every minute. To do this I made Im_Hungry function. The only thing left me to do is triggering this function every minute.
Once I was making discord bot I used CronTrigger function to do somethin similar, so I decited to use it again, but this time in pygame.

thats my code

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_job(Im_Hungry, 'cron', second='0')
sched.start()
```

I also tried to do this this way

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(Im_Hungry, CronTrigger( second = "0"))
 scheduler.start()
```

But it doesnt work.
I tried to put it in main while loop but my program is getting freezed
Have you got any Idea how can I make hungry system done ?

Answer (score 1):

I did it.

I had to put

```
schedule.run_pending()
```

into main loop

and

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(Im_Hungry)
```

at the start of my project